# difference between : build and make in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

For a project JAVA EE in  Intellij IDEA, what is the difference between:
Rebuild Project and Make Project  (in menu Build) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

You can reference https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/compilation-types.html

**Make Project - Only modified**

> All the source files in the entire project that have been modified since the last compilation are compiled. Dependent source files, if appropriate, are also compiled. Additionally, the tasks tied to the compilation or make process on modified sources are performed. For example, EJB validation is performed if the corresponding option is enabled on the Validation page.
>   Refer to the section Making Project for details.

**Rebuild Project. - All files**

> All the source files in the project are recompiled. This may be necessary when the classpath entries have changed, for example, SDKs or libraries being used added, removed or altered.
>   Refer to the section Rebuilding Project for details.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild recompiles all .class files whether they are out of date or not.  Make just recompiles out of date .class files.

Comment: My experience do not show this.Do you have any reference for this idea? I could not find any references that approve your claim.

Comment: References? Not sure I know what you mean.  Go into the directory where your .class files get built and try it for yourself.  Change one file and say make project. Only the file you changed is rebuilt.  Say rebuild project and all .class files regenerated.