# Difference between make and build in the Intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The **Intellij idea** in the build menu has **Make Project** and **Build Project**. what is difference between them?

Comment: Have you tried the documentation: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/compilation-types.html ?

Comment: Make compiles those source files which have changed since the last compilation, while build will compile _all_ source files regardless of whether or not they have been changed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34241974/difference-between-build-and-make-in-intellij-idea

Answer (score 1):

You can get it on the Intelij [site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/compilation-types.html):
**Make Project:** All the source files in the entire project that have been modified since the last compilation are compiled. Dependent source files, if appropriate, are also compiled. Additionally, the tasks tied to the compilation or make process on modified sources are performed. For example, EJB validation is performed if the corresponding option is enabled on the Validation page.

**Rebuild Project:** All the source files in the project are recompiled. This may be necessary when the classpath entries have changed, for example, SDKs or libraries being used added, removed or altered.